# Redirect to error controller in web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I write project WEB API 2 and I'd like to show json result in my custom format when I user wrong url like "localhost/api/v1/" or "localhost/api", for this I tryed to create ErrorController with get request which will return message about error. I add route config to WebApiConfig:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "ErrorInApi",
            "v{version}",
            new {controller ="Error" }     
            );
```

How I can write config to redirect in error controller in all wrong url cases?

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling#registering_exception_filters and this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: @vittore no, thanks I will read

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times you use [exception filters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) to deal with exceptions in web api, however you can use them to deal with exceptions during routing, which is the case OP asks. So you may use two new things web api offers you: [IExceptionLogger and IExceptionHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling) which receive instance of ExceptionContext. Linked page provide sample implementation of such hander and logger.